# How to redirect to external URL upon form submission

Tags: forms, 8, redirection

I've extended a `FormBase` and I've defined the `submitForm` method. In this method I want to redirect to an external URL (https://example.com/my/path?amount=33&gift=0&product_id=1)

```
$myurl = "https://example.com/my/path?amount=33&gift=0&product_id=1";
$redirect = Url::fromUri($myurl);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($redirect);
```

And I get the error:

```
Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.
```

Ok, no problem, let's create one:

```
$myurl = "https://example.com/my/path?amount=33&gift=0&product_id=1";
$redirect = new TrustedRedirectResponse($myurl);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($redirect);
```

Here's the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Form\FormState::setRedirectUrl() must be an instance of Drupal\Core\Url
```

So it appears we've gone full circle. Is there a way that maybe I can convert the `TrustedRedirectResponse` to a `Url` object?

Comment: Using `setResponse` instead of `setRedirectUrl` will address this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use `$form_state->setResponse()` instead to utilize the `TrustedRedirectResponse` you're creating.

Something like this should work:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Do form stuff...

  $myurl = "https://example.com/my/path?amount=33&gift=0&product_id=1";
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse(Url::fromUri($myurl)->toString());
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

This response may be cached depending on your page cache settings. If you need to change this behavior, you can modify the caching metadata. This should disable this type of caching completely for the response (not tested):

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Do form stuff...

  $myurl = "https://example.com/my/path?amount=33&gift=0&product_id=1";
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse(Url::fromUri($myurl)->toString());

  $metadata = $response->getCacheableMetadata();
  $metadata->setCacheMaxAge(0);

  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I may have misinterpreted what you said, but returning a `TrustedRedirectResponse` on the `formSubmit` method just reloaded the page for me - however, it turns out that instead of using `setRedirectUrl` (which only applies to internal paths), one can use `setResponse` and then pass in the TRR object.

Comment: That's correct. I think I got things mixed up with how Controllers return Response objects. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Couple of changes needed here: You're missing `new` infront of TrustedRedirectResponse and you have to call `toString()` on the Url object before passing it into the response constructor. **fixed**

Comment: This worked for me.